# Excel VBA application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble resolving this issue regarding

```
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

My code as below...

```
Dim intX as integer
Dim Uname As String
Dim Pword As String
Dim Epin As String

intX = 9
Uname = Cells(intX, 5)

Do
    If Cells(intX, 4).Value > 0 Then
        Uname = Cells(intX, 5)
        Pword = Cells(intX, 6)
        Epin = Cells(intX, 7)
    Else
        GoTo Skips
    End If

    'Bunch of codes

Skips:
    intX = intX + 1
Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
    
Loop Until IsEmpty(Uname)
```

My table basically has a column of login infos and a column of yes no being informed via a 1 = yes and 0 or null = no system; so if the `cells(intX, 4)` has a 1, it will perform the *bunch of codes*.

`Uname` or `Cells(intX,5)` has value until the end (or empty cell).

The code runs perfectly until the final loop (it finishes the task but returns an application defined or object-defined error hence the code won't run after the `Loop Until IsEmpty(Uname)`.

The error points to

```
If Cells(intX, 4).Value > 0 Then
```

Any help please?

Comment: I suspect `intX` (curious name for a `Long`) is higher than the number of available rows.

Comment: What are the values of `intX` and of `Cells(intX,4)` when the error occurs?  I suspect @Rory answer to be correct, as you do not seem to have any upper bound for checking intX.

Comment: intX at the moment of error is 16, i did an adjustment and made intX back to integer, i made it Long because as it runs, it gives an overflow problem and points to intX = intX + 1

Comment: nothing, as in its a blank cell

Comment: `1.` Are you using `Option Explicit`? `2.` Can you update the code by showing the variable declarations with their specific data type for the purpose their being used?

Comment: Am not using option explicit and code updated as shown

Comment: Why don't you use `Option Explicit` and Click on Debug Compile option? It will help you to write clean code, if you are keen to. And is it a must to loop here?

Comment: Thanks, i switched it on (assuming i did it correctly) same results nothing changed, and yes its a must to loop as i have a few login accounts to scrape data from

Comment: Can you also define the correct worksheet range for this : `Cells(intX, 5)`

Comment: Define the range? Sorry i'm pretty new to VBA, but it goes on Column 5 starting from row 9 until last cell of column 6 (for Column 5 might have some blank cell inbetween)

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't been able to test this code, I sure hope that it is able to run without problems.

```
Dim intX As Integer
Dim Uname As String
Dim Pword As String
Dim Epin As String

For intX = 9 To 1000000
    If Trim(Sheet1.Cells(intX, 5).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Sheet1.Cells(intX, 4).Value2) Then
        If Sheet1.Cells(intX, 4).Value2 > 0 Then
            Uname = Sheet1.Cells(intX, 5).Value2
            Pword = Sheet1.Cells(intX, 6).Value2
            Epin = Sheet1.Cells(intX, 7).Value2
        End If
    Else
        GoTo Skips
    End If

    'Bunch of codes

Skips:
Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If

Next lngrow
```

Here are the things I changed:
- explicit coding vs implicit coding using `Sheet1.` (or what ever sheet you are referring to up front to ensure that Excel is using the sheet you want it to
- explicit coding again using `.value2` at the end
- before checking `.Cells(intX, 4).value2` if it is above zero I added another check if it is actually numeric
- exchanging the endless loop for a definite one
- replacing `IsEmpty` for a comparison against `vbNullString` as `IsEmpty` per help file should be only used to check if a variable has beeen inizialized. But a cell isn't really a variable.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, learned alot here but it didn't give me the results i want, It kept giving me the full row of the Cells(intX, 5) range, which it abandoned IsNumeric (Sheet1.Cells(intX, 4).Value2) Condition

Also Next intX i assume